# c# cEXWB navigate2 doesn't work on second url

Tags: c#

I am trying to use a browser object to get some data from a website. the problem is that for one site i have to redirect, get some other info and then go back to this site.
my coed so far is

```
private void getInfo(cEXWB browser, string url)
{
  if (url == "www.specificwebsite.com")
  {
       browser.navigate2("www.mywebsite.com");
       int myAnswer = getData(browser);
  }
  browser.navigate2(url);
}
```

the problem is that i can NEVER get my browser to navigate 2 times. That is - if i need to navigate to "www.mywebsite.com" - it doesn't navigate to url. 
What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
private void getInfo(cEXWB browser, string url)
{
  if (url == "www.specificwebsite.com")
  {
       browser.navigate("www.mywebsite.com");
       int myAnswer = getData(browser);
  }
  browser.navigate(url);
}
```

I think that `browser.navigate2("www.mywebsite.com");`
the 2 is messing it up

Answer (score 1):

You should wait till first navigation is completed.

It should be something like:...

```
browser.Navigated += (sender, webBrowserNavigatedEventArgs) =>
{
     int myAnswer = getData(browser);
     browser.Navigate(secondurl);
};
browser.Navigate(firsturl);
```

Comment: do i need to add a browser.Navigated event for every url? that is - my actual program has more than one specific url (i use a switch there) - do i need to add an event for each?

Comment: In fact, you shouldn't. One browser, one Navigated event.